# Bayesian hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, bayesian, hypothesis-testing

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_4$ be a sample taken from the uniform dstribution with the density 
$$
f_{\theta}(x)=\theta^{-1} \cdot 1_{(0,\theta)}(x).
$$
Assume that $\theta$ is a random variable with the density 
$$
\pi (\theta)=\frac{4}{3}\theta^4 e^{-2 \theta}\cdot 1_{(0,\infty)}(\theta).
$$
We reject $H_0: \theta\leq 3$ (with $H_1: \theta > 3$) for all such $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ for which the posteriori probability of the set $\{\theta: \theta>3\}$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$. Calculate the significance level of a test.

Could you help me please with this exercise? It is taken from the actuary exam organized in my country - for me this is the hardest exercise ever. I even don't know what *significance level of a test* is in Bayesian contecst.

My work so far: I am able to calculate a posteriori probability: it has the shifted exponential distribution with the density
$$
l(\theta|x_1,\ldots,x_4)=2e^{-2(\theta-\max\{x_i\})}1_{(\max\{x_i\},\infty)}(\theta).
$$

Comment: Presumably you have to start by calculating the $k$ such that you will reject $H_0$ if $\max\{x_i\} \gt k$.

Comment: This is the very easy part, the problem is: what next? What is in fact definition of the significance level in this case? As the probability of $\{\theta:\theta>3\} >\frac{1}{2}$ iff $e^{2(\max\{x_i\}-\max\{3,\max\{x_i\}\})}>\frac{1}{2}$, Henry's $k$ is equal to $3-\frac{\ln 2}{2}$. But what I should do next?

Comment: I don't know, but I might guess at calculating the probability that $\max\{X_i\} \gt k$ conditioned on $\theta \le 3$ using the prior distribution, i.e. the probability of erroneously rejecting $H_0$ when it is true.

Comment: But wait Henry. You sugest that I should calculate $P(\max\{X_i\}>k|\theta\leq 3)$, are you? But how I could calculate $P(\max\{X_i\}>k \cap \theta\leq 3)$, as the distribution $\max\{X_i\}$ depends on $\theta$, since $\max\{X_i\}$ has the density $f(t)=\frac{4}{\theta^4}t^3 1_{(0,\theta)}(t)$ which depends on $\theta$, which is again random? Could you give some hint?

Comment: OK, now I understand what you mean, Henry, and my answer is the same as it should be (0.388), so thank you really very much for your hits!

Answer (score 0):

To repeat my comments, since they appear to have been helpful:

> Presumably you have to start by calculating the $k$ such that you will
>   reject $H_0$ if $\max\{x_i\}\gt k$.
>
> I might guess at calculating the significance as the probability that
>   $\max\{X_i\}\gt k$ conditioned on $\theta \le 3$ using the prior
>   distribution, i.e. the probability of erroneously rejecting $H_0$ when
>   it is true.